# how to print rows based on latest date in each month

Tags: text-processing

I have a file in Linux with below content. I want to print the rows with maximum date value in each month based on date value in column col3.The data is already sorted in descending order by col3.

```
col1|col2|col3
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
hds|fsfs|2024-02-28
fdg|sffe|2024-02-27
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdf|gfgfg|2024-01-30
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
fgf|yjyjy|2023-12-30
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
gfgfg|uysdfd|2023-11-27
```

Expected output :

```
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print rows with maximum date value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772213/how-to-print-rows-with-maximum-date-value)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' The questions are sufficiently different to warrant different solutions.  I would however not be the least surprised if there are (separate) duplicates to them in the system.

Comment: @Kusalananda based on [OP's comment there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772213/how-to-print-rows-with-maximum-date-value#comment1474552_772213), this is what OP actually wanted there too, they just didn't word it well enough. The questions might be different as given, but either that one should be closed as unclear or this one should be closed as a duplicate that was meant to be an edit.

Comment: @muru Out of those options, I suggest flagging the other question as unclear. Personally, I wouldn't do it, as I still think they are separate issues, regardless of the intended formulation, and that the questions and answers there could potentially be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

With [Miller (`mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), reading the data as a CSV file called `file` that uses `|` (pipe) as the field delimiter, we can parse out the year and month from the `col3` field and get the first value for each year+month combination:

```bash
mlr --csv --fs pipe \
    put 'd = splita($col3, "-"); $y=d[1]; $m=d[2]' then \
    head -n 1 -g y,m then \
    cut -x -f y,m file
```

The Miller `put` expression,

```
d  = splita($col3, "-");
$y = d[1];
$m = d[2];
```

... creates a temporary array, `d`, from the datestamp by splitting the datestamp on dashes.  We then create the two new fields `y` (the year) and `m` (the month) from the split up parts.

With `head -n 1 -g y,m` we then get the first value for each year+month group.

The `cut` operation at the end removes the `y` and `m` fields that we no longer need.

If the data is unsorted, an extra sorting step will need to be applied at the start (or at least before `head`):

```bash
mlr --csv --fs pipe \
    sort -r col3 then \
    put 'd = splita($col3, "-"); $y=d[1]; $m=d[2]' then \
    head -n 1 -g y,m then \
    cut -x -f y,m file
```

To get header-less CSV output, use `mlr` with its `--headerless-csv-output` (or `--ho`) option.

---

Example run on the given data:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs pipe --headerless-csv-output sort -r col3 then put 'd = splita($col3, "-"); $y=d[1]; $m=d[2]' then head -n 1 -g y,m then cut -x -f y,m file
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
```

Comment: Thanks Kusalanada for looking into issue. Unfortunately, we don't have mlr. The other solution using awk worked. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @JosinAbraham `mlr` is easily installable on all mainstream Unix variants.

Answer (score 1):

A shell script that uses sqlite3 to do all the work:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Filename to process is only arg to script

sqlite3 <<EOF
.mode list
.headers off
.import '$1' data
WITH ranked_dates AS
 (SELECT col1, col2, col3, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY strftime('%Y-%m', col3) ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS date_rank
  FROM data)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM ranked_dates
WHERE date_rank = 1
ORDER BY col3 DESC
EOF
```

example:

```bash
$ ./maxdates dates.txt
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
```

---

this one works on input data that's in any order instead of assuming it's already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk, take your pick:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1 && !seen[substr($NF,1,7)]++' file
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
```

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && !seen[substr($0,length()-9,7)]++' file
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
```

```
$ awk -F'[-|]' 'NR>1 && !seen[$(NF-2)$(NF-1)]++' file
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
```

Answer (score 0):

As the highest date in each month comes first, you just need to skip following year-month duplications. So something like (now tested):

```
awk -F'|' '
    FNR == 1 { next; }
    { ym = substr ($3, 1, 7); }
    ! (ym in YM) { YM[ym]; print; }
'
```

Comment: Thank you  Paul_Pedant. Your solution worked!! Thanks so much. Really appreciate your timely help.

Comment: @JosinAbraham If a solution was helpful, consider up-voting it. If it resolves your problem, also consider "accepting" it. Questions with accepted solutions are marked as resolved.  Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'lines[0].put;  my @a = lines.map: *.split: "|";  my $b = @a.map: *.[2];   
            my  %c = $b.classify( { $_.Date.month }, :as{ $_ => $++ } );  
            for %c.map(*.value.max.values).flat.sort -> $n {    
                @a[$n].join("|").put; 
            };'  file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'lines[0].put;  my @a = lines.map: *.split: "|";  my $b = @a.map: *.[2];  
            my %c = $b.classify( { $_.Date.month }, :as{ $_ => $++ } ); 
            put @a[$_].join("|") for %c.map(*.value.max.values).flat.sort;'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family. One feature of Raku is built-in support for ***ISO 8601*** `Date`s. This means once you call `Date` on a value, it gets checked for validity. So with the given dataset, `2024-02-29` works just fine, but `2024-02-30` throws a `Day out of range` error.

The code above should work fine even if lines are not in date-order:

1. Read the header (`lines[0]`) and immediately out`put`.
2. Read remaining `lines`, `split` on `|` bar, save to `@a` array.
3. Copy 3rd (date) column into `$b` scalar.
4. Using the built-in `Date` and `month` routines, `classify` the `$b` scalar by month, using `:as` return both the date and the `$++` line-number ***as*** a {key `=>` value} pair, save to `%c` hash.
5. Element-wise, `map` into `%c` hash, select out the month-wise `*.value.max`, which allows us to then take the line-number (using `.values` because that's how we set up the key/values). Returns the index `(0 3 5 7)`.
6. Iterate through the index, out`put`ting the correct positions of the original `@a` array, with columns `join`ed back on `|`.

Sample Input:

```
col1|col2|col3
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
hds|fsfs|2024-02-28
fdg|sffe|2024-02-27
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdf|gfgfg|2024-01-30
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
fgf|yjyjy|2023-12-30
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
gfgfg|uysdfd|2023-11-27
```

Sample Output:

```
col1|col2|col3
abc|xyz|2024-02-29
dfr|jfdfd|2024-01-31
fdg|rgrg|2023-12-31
gfgf|hhfdfd|2023-11-28
```

*NOTE: Sometimes it is helpful to look at a language's internal representation of data, so here's what `%c` hash looks like after Step 4 (sorted in month order):*

```perl
~$ raku -e 'lines[0].skip; my @a = lines.map: *.split: "|"; my $b = @a.map: *.[2];  my %c = $b.classify( { $_.Date.month }, :as{ $_ => $++ } ); say %c.sort(*.key.Int);'  file
(1 => [2024-01-31 => 3 2024-01-30 => 4] 2 => [2024-02-29 => 0 2024-02-28 => 1 2024-02-27 => 2] 11 => [2023-11-28 => 7 2023-11-27 => 8] 12 => [2023-12-31 => 5 2023-12-30 => 6])
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Date
https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap#Mutable_hashes_and_immutable_maps
https://raku.org